# Displaying existing tags from a post with MagicSuggest

Tags: jquery, magicsuggest

I'm using magicsuggest to allow users to add tags to posts they create.

When a user edits a post he has tagged and published, I need to display the exiting tags for that post which a user previously entered.

I cannot use the `value: [1,3,5]` method that magicsuggest has, for certain reasons, so i generate the form with all the tags that were stored, in the same way MagicSuggest structures them. But when I load the page, MagicSuggest clears the entire form. How can I stop it from doing this, and how can I display existing tags for a post?

**Eg: loadPost.php**

`select title, description, tags from posts where postId = 159`

**Output using php**

```
<div class="container">
        <form action="subscribe.php" method="post">
            <div class="ms-ctn " style="" id="ms">
            <span class="ms-helper " style="display: none;"></span>
            <div class="ms-sel-ctn">
            <div class="ms-sel-item ">Andorra<span class="ms-close-btn"></span></div>
            <div class="ms-sel-item ">Armenia<span class="ms-close-btn"></span></div>
            <div class="ms-sel-item ">Bosnia and Herzegovina<span class="ms-close-btn"></span></div>
            <div class="ms-sel-item ">Belgium<span class="ms-close-btn"></span></div>
            <input type="text" class="" placeholder="">
            <div style="display: none;">
                <input type="hidden" name="countries[]" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="countries[]" value="7">
                <input type="hidden" name="countries[]" value="16">
                <input type="hidden" name="countries[]" value="19">
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

From here on, a user can edit existing tags (above), or add new ones. But I cant seem to be able to display his existing tags, since the form gets cleared by magicsuggest.

Any way to do this?

Comment: Is that your php code or is that the HTML rendered after the component was initialized?

Comment: @karlipoppins That is the HTML rendered by the php. Ive written a function to output it the way you see in the question. Once the page loads, magicsuggest clears all that you see.

Comment: You should not be doing that in your php code. The component needs to render itself, initialize properly with its events according to the passed options or it won't work properly. See the tutorial part 5 it does exactly what you're asking for